# Looking for a quote - "Philosophy began when ..." or something

Tags: history, quote

I am looking for a quote. I don't recall by whom, but it goes something like this. *Philosophy began when men had time to be lazy* - anyone?

Comment: Many philosophers and historians have noted that pure intellectual reasearch can start only when certain basic needs are already met and people have leisure time. From ancient Greek thought, to Marx and Engels to modern anthropologists.

Comment: As @NikosM. said there are many examples of this idea, an early version can be found in [this section](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.01.0052:book%3D1:section%3D981b) of Aristotle's *Metaphysics*: "Hence when all the discoveries of this kind were fully developed, the sciences which relate neither to pleasure nor yet to the necessities of life were invented, and first in those places where men had leisure. Thus the mathematical sciences originated in the neighborhood of Egypt, because there the priestly class was allowed leisure."

Comment: @Hypnosifl, I think several sophists, claimed this before Aristotle, but have no reference at this point

Comment: It should be noted that all people have philosophy in the sense of basic rules of living, no matter their leisure time. However systematic philosophy about abstract concepts requires that there is a certain ease of living. One cannot debate abstracts when one is hungry